# Как убрать -webkit-transform из transition-property: top, transform;

Tags: css

Есть стиль: `transition-property: top, transform;`

При загрузке в браузере, браузер дописывает -webkit-transform. Итого: `transition-property: top, transform, -webkit-transform;`

Как убрать -webkit-transform - он мешает правильной анимации элемента

Comment: Попробуйте   -webkit-transition-property: top, transform;
-moz-transition-property: top, transform;
transition-property: top, transform;

Comment: @T0hich71 - не помогло

Comment: !important воткните